# Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html) found

Tags: apache

I am using `apache` as reverse proxy server for my `dotnet` application(`dotnet core` api) which is hosted in `centos` and I am using `systemd` service to execute this api. sometimes I am receiving "no matching DirectoryIndex found" error. I found similar topic in internet but none of them helped me to resolve this issue. Can someone help me on this issue?

**Detailed error mentioned below.**

> [autoindex:error] [pid 18716] [client xx:xx:xx:xx:48918] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive

Comment: Is there a file named index.html inside /var/www/html?    What about permissions?

Comment: sorry for the late reply.. Yes , there is index.html file and having permissions too. As I mentioned in the post, I do not receive this error every time.So my assumption is that it is not related to permission.

Comment: hum, sometimes only...  Then look at the performance statistics (setup the /status page).  You may not have enough client processes / threads to serve your traffic?

Comment: I am new to linux. could you please tell me how to setup status page?

Comment: Documentation: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_status.html